# I can't make a bootstrap form responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have two forms of which I want a fixed full screen size, but trying all bootstrap options they don't become responsive at lower resolutions.

what should i do to make them responsive? here is the code:

```
  <form action='' method="post">
  <div class="mb-3" style="width: 800px;">
  <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1" class="form-label">Write your review</label>
  <textarea name="messaggio" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="8" placeholder="your review"></textarea>
  </div>
  <p>Language Review :
  <select name="language" class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example"style="width: 400px;" >
      <option value="english">English</option>
      <option value="deutsche">Deutsche</option>
      <option value="español">Español</option>
      <option value="français">Français</option>
      <option value="italiano">Italiano</option>
```

Comment: Please share a complete code and provide necessary information, please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `<div class="mb-3" style="width: 800px;">` — why would you expect that to be remotely responsive? It's going to be 800px wide. Full stop.

Comment: sorry code tag it doesn't allow me to put all the code, there is only one submit after, bootstrap 5.

Comment: what i want is 800px in hd, but let it decrease the width at lower resolutions

Comment: Try this,
width: 100%; and max-width: 800;
https://jsfiddle.net/Stephen2hats/cjmzhd7q/

Comment: You absolutely _can_ put a complete form in the post above. Link the Bootstrap libraries via CDN.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove inline css from the div `<div class="mb-3" style="width: 800px;">`.